# Trying to get the sum of all votes from my voting table but i get an error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
<?php

$totalvotes = ("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM voting WHERE votes >= 0 ");

    $totalvotesresults = mysql_query( $totalvotes )
or die( "Could not get total votes " .mysql_error() );

$data = mysql_fetch_array( $totalvotesresults );
echo "<div>Total number of votes is ". $data['votes'] ."</div>\n";;
?>
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Assuming each row in your database is worth one vote, you could use `$totalVotes = mysql_num_rows( $totalvotesresults );`  (http://ca3.php.net/mysql_num_rows)

Answer (score 4):

You call the result of your `COUNT(*)` query `total` but use `votes` in your PHP:

```
echo "<div>Total number of votes is ". $data['votes'] ."</div>\n";
```

should be:

```
echo "<div>Total number of votes is ". $data['total'] ."</div>\n";
```

[Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: I added a slight change to the white-spacing on your answer John, but otherwise you are right on.